# Pass parameters to Windows Service to fire method

Tags: windows-services, parameters

I'm attempting to build a Windows Service which will execute some method when a user clicks a button in a WinForms application. I'd like to be able to pass in a few strings when the user presses the GUI button which will have the service consume them and processes a specific method. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is a handy way to handle interprocess communication.  Configure it to use named pipes and it can listen for your request.  Or use the MSMQ option instead if you really don't care about the response.

Answer (score 0):

Check our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) (free with source), which has been created for tasks similar to yours. It's fast and has API similar to windows messages api.